# JS stop working after jquery .load content

Tags: javascript, php

Please help me to understand why js stop working after .load THE SAME CONTENT in div.

```
<main class="container">
    <div id="reload_div">
        <div id="color_div" style="width:100px;height:100px; background:red; margin-bottom: 100px">
            orig
        </div>
        <button id="make_it_green" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            make it green
        </button>
    </div>
    <button id="reload_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-top:20px">
        reload
    </button>
</main>

<script>
$("#make_it_green").click(function(){
  $("#color_div").css("background","green")
}); 

$("#reload_btn").click(function(){
  $("#reload_div").fadeTo(300,0, function () {
    $("#reload_div").load ("reload.php", 
    {  }, function () {
        $("#reload_div").fadeTo(300,1, function () {
        });
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

After .load the same content in "reload_div" #make_it_green button stop working!
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code as you have posted it, the event handler is added to the `make_it_green` button.

Once you load the new content with jQuery the element to which the handler was attached no longer exists, so the event handler no longer exists. You load a new element with the same name, but there's no event handler attached unless you attach the event handler again.

Alternatively, attach the event handler to the containing `div` and delegate the event handling.

```
$("#reload_div").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check the id of the original target element. If it's 
        // our button, change the colour.
        if (e.target.id === "make_it_green") {
            $("#color_div").css("background", "green");
        }
    });
```

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#setting_a_listener_on_a_parent_element) on MDN for a detailed discussion of event delegation

Comment: @ Tangentially Perpendicular 
thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ВячеславВето You're welcome. If this has helped you please remember to accept the answer.